# Функция нахождения взаимно простых чисел на JS

Tags: javascript, функции

Всем привет! Решаю задачи на написание функций.Условие одной из задач:
Положительные целые числа, не имеющие общих делителей, кроме тривиальной единицы, называются взаимно простыми.

Говоря другими словами, два числа можно назвать взаимно простыми, если их наибольший общий делитель(НОД) равен единице.

Напишите функцию, которая параметрами будет принимать два числа и проверять - взаимно простые они или нет.
Моё решение:

```js
   function getEasyDivisor(num1, num2){
    if(getNod(num1, num2)==1){
        alert('Эти числа взаимно простые')
    }else{
        alert('Числа НЕ взаимно простые')
    }
    }
    console.log(getEasyDivisor(100,300));

    function getNod(num1, num2){ // возвращает наименьший общий делитель
    let resNod=[];
    let arr1=getDivisor(num1);
    let arr2=getDivisor(num2);
    resNod=getObsch(arr1, arr2);
    function getMinOfArray(resNod) {
        return Math.min.apply(null, resNod);
        }
        return getMinOfArray(resNod);
    }
    function getObsch(arr1, arr2){ // сравнивая два массива,выводит общие делители
    let resObsch=[];
    for(let elem of arr1){
        if(!inArr(elem,arr2)){
            resObsch.push(elem)
        }
    }return resObsch;
    }
    function getDivisor(num){ // находит делители числа.
    let resDiv=[];
    for(let i=1; i<num; i++){
        if(num%i==0){
            resDiv.push(i);
        }
    }return resDiv;
    }
    function inArr(elem,arr){ // ищет элем. в массиве.
    return arr.indexOf(elem)===-1;
    }
```

Мне кажется подозрительно гладко всё. Подскажите, в чём я возможно ошибся и как было бы правильно?

Comment: работает правильно? ps. правильно было бы расставлять отступы

Comment: Эникейщик, работает, но я не уверен, что правильно.

Comment: в смысле не уверен? как тут можно быть неуверенным? Или правильно, или неправильно. Делаешь несколько тестов с разными числами и проверяешь.

Comment: Эникейщик, понимаешь, как какие бы числа ни вводишь - всегда выдаёт ответ, что взаимно простые.

Comment: значит неправильно, разве тут могут быть какие-то сомнения..

Comment: А вы в школе не изучали НОД?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ошибка с одной стороны небольшая, всего в двух буквах, с другой стороны, в коде написано совершенно противоположное тому, что требуется.

Из задания:

> два числа можно назвать взаимно простыми, если их **наибольший** общий делитель(НОД) равен единице.

Из кода:

> function getNod(num1, num2){ // возвращает **наименьший** общий делитель

Нужно заменить `min` на `max`

```
return Math.max.apply(null, resNod);
```

Comment: Эникейщик, спасибо!)